# Android Studio の完全アンインストール法

Tags: android-studio

Flutterでアプリ開発を行っているのですが、実機でテストしようとするとエラーになるのでいったんAndroid Studioを完全アンインストールしてはじめからやり直そうと思っているのですが、できません。

[Windows（v10）からAndroid Studioを完全にアンインストールする方法は？](https://tutorialmore.com/questions-1487492.htm)

上記ページを見ると `.AndroidStudio` を削除するなどと書かれているのですが、自分の環境では存在しません。他をすべて削除して再インストールしても、プロジェクトやプラグインがそのまま残ってしまいます。
どうしたら完全アンインストールできるでしょう？

Comment: 念のため確認しますが、Android StudioはWindowsにインストールしたのですよね？エクスプローラでC:\Users\%username%を開いても.androidや.AndroidStudioで始まるフォルダが存在しないということですね。

Comment: Windowsで、.androidは存在しますが.AndroidStudioは存在しませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/3809427 に書かれてるものに加え、コメント欄にある
%AppData%/Local/Google/AndroidStudio* %AppData%/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio*
を削除することで完全アンインストールできました。